# How do I perform padding operations on an inconsistent field using JOLT left/rightpad

Tags: java, json, jolt

Let's say I have the following input:

```
{
    "input": {
        "string": "the QuIcK brOwn fox"
    }
}
```

I am trying to pad the 'string' field to a specific length. Utilising the following would not be possible:

```
"basic1": "=leftPad('the QuIcK brOwn fox', 30, 'X')"
```

The **value** of the 'string' field will be dynamic and subject to **change** each time. Hence I require a transformation that can be applied to the 'string' **key** as opposed to simply manipulating the **value**.

I have tried the following in the jolt transform demo website:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "rightPad": {
        "basic4": "=rightPad(@(2,string), 30, 'X')" // happy path : actually pad a looked up string from the data
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am receving the following output on the demo website for JOLT:

```
{
  "input" : {
    "string" : "the QuIcK brOwn fox"
  },
  "rightPad" : { }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aziz, What's your expected output exactly ? Do you want to pad X values to the right upto 30 chars length ?

Comment: I would like the entire output field to consist of 30 characters. i.e. "the quick brown foxXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: I mean Do you want to have this `{
  "input" : {
    "string" : "the QuIcK brOwn foxXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}` as an example based onn the current one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **modify** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // overwrites the value of the "string" attribute
        "string": "=rightPad(@(1,&), 30, 'X')" 
        // @(1,&) looks for the current level 
        // with replicated value of "string" due to the ampersand
      }
    }
  }
]
```